# What is retired out in cricket?

Tags: rules, cricket

I have seen a match score card, where Mitali Raj (India) was shown **retd out**.

What is "retired out" in cricket? When is a player declared retired out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is very clearly covered by [Law 2.9](https://www.lords.org/mcc/laws-of-cricket/laws/law-2-substitutes-and-runners-batsman-or-fielder-leaving-the-field-batsman-retiring-or-batsman-commencing-innings/):

> Batsman retiring
>
> A batsman may retire at any time during his innings when the ball is dead. The umpires, before allowing play to proceed shall be informed of the reason for a batsman retiring.
>
> (a) If a batsman retires because of illness, injury or any other unavoidable cause, he is entitled to resume his innings subject to (c) below. If for any reason he does not do so, his innings is to be recorded as ‘Retired - not out’.
>
> (b) If a batsman retires for any reason other than as in (a) above, he may resume his innings only with the consent of the opposing captain. If for any reason he does not resume his innings it is to be recorded as ‘Retired - out’.

As the Cricbuzz scorecard you've linked to indicates, this was a bit of a strange situation in that the Indian Women continued to bat after reaching their target of 107 runs - basically at this point it had turned into a practice match, so a couple of the Indian women retired to let the rest of the team have a go.

Comment: Spot on. Just one addition to that - under the [new laws](https://www.lords.org/mcc/laws-of-cricket/new-code-of-laws-october-2017/), a batsman who is removed from the field for offensive behaviour will also be recorded "Retired - out" (I'm a little surprised they didn't create a new category of dismissal to record that. "Retired - a**hole" isn't something a batsman would want on his record after all!). Those laws will come into effect on 1 Oct 2017.